# data processing in MVVM pattern

Tags: android, mvvm

Whose role is processing data in the **MVVM** pattern?

For example, if you need to display a Date object in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` on one screen and `mm-dd-yyyy` on another screen, who's the role of View or ViewModel?

If this is the role of View I use `@BindingAdapter`,
If it is the role of ViewModel, use `Livedata<Date>().map {/* format */ }`

What's the better way to the **MVVM** pattern?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **view model** of MVVM is a **value converter**, meaning the view model is responsible for exposing (converting) the data objects from the model in such a way that objects are easily managed and presented. In this respect, the view model is more model than view, and handles most if not all of the **view's display logic**.

So conceptually and implementation wise the logic or transformation should be in View Model.

Answer (score 1):

Better in ViewModel. If you switch from DataBinding in the future, your mapping logic will persist in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the original "long" timestamp inside the viewmodel and then decide based on requirements where to transform the data into string. One good point to keep the string inside the viewmodel is that it does the transformation only once, and keep the data until lifecycle ends. While the binding adapter will do the conversion everytime you bind the view. At the same time the string will be kept in memory until lifecycle ends.